# How to setup a service that accepts input via ssh, run python scripts using the input and then return the output over ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, services

I have a server that runs ubuntu and has GPUs that run large deep learning models. I would like for this server machine to first accept requests that contain an input over SSH, then feed that input to the DL models to get outputs (running the models via python scripts btw), and finally return the output over SSH back to the original sender. How would I go about this? I thought of setting up a service but perhaps there are better ways to do so. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`man sshd`; section `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT`; option `command="command"`

Here's an example:

```
$ head ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="cat > /home/vagrant/ssh-output" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...
$ ls ssh-output
ls: cannot access 'ssh-output': No such file or directory
$ echo 'blah blah blah' | ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa localhost 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
$ cat ssh-output 
blah blah blah
```

Observe that no shell was spawned.  Instead, the contents piped into `ssh` on the client side, were passed to stdin of cat on the ssh-server side.  For your scenario, you'd replace `command=""` with the path to your python script.

Note, you have to know the user and pub_key of the user before you can configure this for them; this isn't a generic configuration.  Now, if you publish the username and a private key, then you can tell your users to use those, and provide this as a generic service, but shared private keys (especially published/commonly available keys) are ripe for abuse.

Also note, this configuration would allow clients to open port forwards or X11 forwards to that machine.  This can be restricted; I'll point you to the man page for that.

Comment: "Observe that no shell was spawned" – Not true. In case of SSH there is *always* a shell, unless you connect to an internal subsystem (I think so far `internal-sftp` is the only one, at least in OpenSSH), which does not happen here. Here the shell is responsible for handling `>`. The shell may have automatically `exec`ed to `cat` in no time, so it may have *appeared* there was no shell at all. Maybe you mean no shell was presented to the connecting user to interact with. This is true.